# RxJS Angular2 Component interaction with Observables

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to make 2 different components interact with each other using service. I'm trying to do this with Observable. The idea is that `account.component.ts` will use `popup.service.ts` to show a popup `popup.component.ts`. And inside popup there is a button which needs to run a function inside `account.component.ts` after being pressed inside popup.

Account component

```
export class AccountViewComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(popupService: PopupService) { }
    openCancelPopup() {
        let popup = {
            'title': 'Popup title!',
            'body': 'Are you really sure you wish to cancel your subscription?'
        };
        this.popupService.showPopup(popup);
        this.popupService.modalButton.subscribe(
            success => {
                // If OK button was pressed, continue 
                console.log(success);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Popup service

```
@Injectable()
export class PopupService {
    showPopupEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    modalButton: Observable<any>;
    constructor() { }

    showPopup(data: Object) {
        this.showPopupEmitter.emit(data);
    }
}
```

Popup component

```
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {
    showPopup: boolean = false;
    title: string;
    body: string;
    constructor(private popupService: PopupService) { }

    close() {
        this.showPopup = false;
    }

    openPopup(data) {
        this.title = data.title;
        this.body = data.body;
        this.showPopup = true;
        this.popupService.popupButton = new Observable(value => {
            value.next(true);

// I want to "resolve" here via button press

        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.popupService.showPopupEmitter.subscribe(data => this.openPopup(data));
    }
}
```

Current state is that popup is shown and the observable is "resolved" instantly. How do I "resolve" it via button press so I could continue with my function inside `account.component.ts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a `Subject` which is an object that is both an observer and an observable.

```
popupSubject = new Subject<bool>();
```

Subscribing to the subject is as easy as:

```
// You can chain as many Rx operators on this as you want
let mySubscription = this.popupSubject.asObservable();
```

And passing a value through it is just

```
popupSubject.next(true)
```

Whenever the button is pressed.